# Apache Mesos: sharing disk space?

Tags: apache, mesos, mesosphere

I know apache mesos gives resource offers for based on cpu/mem.
Can it also schedule volume space to different framework so each framework can use up to certain amount of space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Mesos can be used to allocate disk resources to frameworks. See the `disk` [resource type](https://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/attributes-resources/).

By default, a task will be allowed to exceed its allocated disk space. Mesos supports different mechanisms for enforcing disk space allocation: see the "POSIX Disk Isolator" and "XFS Disk Isolator" sections in the [containerizer docs](https://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/mesos-containerizer/).